# Prime made from the digits of $\sqrt{22}$

Tags: number-theory

Which is the smallest prime derived from the digits of $\sqrt{22}$, where the 4
before the comma is not considered ?

To be more precise :

$x:=\sqrt{22}-4$   , so $x = 0,690415...$

for every natural number n : a(n):=truncate(x*10^n) , a(n) gives the first n digits
of x

Which is the smallest number n such that a(n) is prime ?

Comment: Does anyone know, if magma can calculate sqrt(22) up to, lets say, 10 000 digits ? In PARI, this can be achieved with default(realprecision,10000), but I did not find such a command in magma.

Comment: Why would one ask oneself such a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maple didn't find any up to $n=4000$.

Heuristically,  a number of $n$ decimal digits  has probability $ \sim 1/(n \ln 10)$ of being prime, so up to $n=10^N$ you
would expect about $\ln(N)/\ln(10)$ primes. So it's not unlikely that you'll need to look at billions of digits of $\sqrt{22}$ before you get a prime.

Comment: Mathematica did not find one up to $n=15000$. The number $22$ seems special. For $\sqrt{23}=4.795831523\dots$ there is a prime for $n=1$. For $\sqrt{21}=4.582575695\dots$ there is a prime for $n=8$. For $\pi$ the first prime appears at $n=5$.